# Javascript: move new element after createElement

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have created a zombie img in my banner div but I can't get the img to move to the left after it has been created.

createZombie function is on a timer:

```
createZombieTimer = window.setInterval(createZombie, 1000);
```

That is in an init() that loads with the body.

```
function createZombie(){
    var imgElem = document.createElement("img");
    imgElem.src = "img/zombie_walk_right.gif";
    var newZom = document.getElementById('banner').appendChild(imgElem);
    newZom.style.height = "40px";
    newZom.style.width = "auto";
    newZom.style.display = "block";
newZom.style.marginLeft = "50px";
    var zomPos = parseInt(newZom.style.marginLeft);

    if (zomPos > 0) {
        newZom.style.marginLeft = (zomPos + 50) + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the margin for the element only once. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I set the margin again. Is that what you meant? I am still not getting the img that I created to move..

Comment: You set the marginLeft in `newZom.style.marginLeft = "50px";`, and then you override it in `newZom.style.marginLeft = (zomPos + 50) + "px";` based on a condition. This override is, however, not noticable to the user, since the item isn't rendered inbetween.

Comment: @weeknie do you mean that I need to re-define `newZom.style.marginLeft` before the if statement?

Comment: First, what do you actually want? Do you want it to move, over a short time, from it's initial position to the left? If so, look into https://api.jquery.com/animate/. If not, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @weeknie I want each new img to move to the right 50px every second after it has been created. I am trying to do this w/o jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's clear from the comments now what you want to do, I'll post it here as the answer.

You can do this with plain javascript as well. What you will have to do, is use `setInterval()`. This will execute a function every second, in which you can update the position of the elements.

Example:

```
// Function to move the zombie by 50 pixels
function moveZombie()
{
    // Select the zombie element (will need additional logic to select all of them, just an example)
    zomElement = document.getElementById('zombie1');
    zomPos = parseInt(zomElement.style.marginLeft);
    zomElement.style.marginLeft = (zomPos + 50) + 'px';
}

// Call this function every second
setInterval(moveZombie(), 1000);
```